# SSIS Excel source refer to the only Sheet ( Loop thru all Excel)

Tags: ssis

now I have bunch of .xls files which I need edit to rename the only sheet = Sheet1, b'z it's set in Excel source as hard coded Sheet1, is there any  trick to refer to the only avail Sheet, which can have different names in my case. I use For Each loop with this.
[image]
Tx
Dai

Comment: I have several answers regarding this process. I will search for it and post a link.

Comment: I use C# based on my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722486/ssis-excel-import-worksheet-variable-or-wildcard

Answer (score 2):

I use the follow script task (C#), this will work well if there is always one sheet with an unknown name:

Variables:

[image]

Control Flow:

[image: Control Flow]

Script Task Setup:

[image: Script task set up]

Make sure variable is read/write

The code:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection objConn;
DataTable dt;

string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Dts.Variables["fName"] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";"
objConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
objConn.Open();

dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbShemaGuid.Tables,null);
objConn.Close();

foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
   //for some reason there is always a duplicate sheet with underscore.
   string t = r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); 

   //Note if more than one sheet exist this will only capture the last one
   if(t.Substring(t.Length-1)!="_")
   {
       Dts.Variables["SheetName"].Value = t;
   }
}
```

And then in SSIS, I add another variable (SQL) to build my SQL.

add expression SQL = "Select * from [" + @SheetName + "]"

Finally set your datasource to that SQL variable in Excel Source.

[image: ExcelCommand]

Note: Make sure you delay validation on Excel Connection in properties.

Note: Make sure you make an expression on Excel Conn for ConnString to "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + @fName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";"

Comment: Thanks, K and all, I tried but looks like miss some points,so I 1. Add Script Task into FOR LOOP BOX   or Add Script Component inside  its TASK.

Comment: 2. Bit confused with  "new variable "Select * from [" + "Your Variable" + "]", I t hought that script will populate this Var, and it's defined inside the script.

Comment: i'll add some images with an explanation

Comment: Images and explanation added. it's hard to do for me because I can't see images at work in answer