# How to change month dynamiquely where loading Excel Files with SSIS

Tags: excel, variables, parameters, ssis

I have to load each month files using SSIS.
I've built a package for January. But I'm not able to use it for February.

- I've created user variable Month equal to 'January$' witch is the Excel Sheet name but I don't know how to use it in order to be changed automatically in the next load (For February).
- Also there is a date column in Excel file and tried to extract the month without success[image]

Can anyone help?
Thanks
Lina

Comment: I have done this with a script task in the past. This is old code for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018642/ssis-excel-source-refer-to-the-only-sheet-loop-thru-all-excel/48025655#48025655

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect time to use an expression within your User variable so it can be dynamically updated with the month change.

I would create another User variable and set it up with the following expression:

###### User::MonthName

```
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 1 ? "January" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 2 ? "February" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 3 ? "March" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 4 ? "April" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 5 ? "May" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 6 ? "June" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 7 ? "July" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 8 ? "August" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 9 ? "September" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 10 ? "October" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 11 ? "November" : 
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 12 ? "December" : ""
```

This will convert the current date into an integer value for the month, and then convert that into the month name. (You can change the GETDATE() to another date variable if needed)

After the variable has been created, I would use that in place of where you have "January" right now in your variable for "January$". For the variable you have right now that's returning "January$", it would have an expression that looks something like:

```
@[User::MonthName] + "$"
```